# Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to do read only call like get call.

```
public TaskModel intializeTaskById(final long taskId){
...
}
```

then why does it require transaction?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, your question header and description is not giving any clarification.

Comment: if you use annotations try putting @Transactional above the function

Comment: why i need the transaction for reading data from Data base ?